# regex - replace word based on first two characters - R

Tags: r

I'm new to regexs and trying to replace entire words based on the first two characters of a string.  For example, if I have a data frame called automobiles and a variable called cars, I'd like to replace Honda with Japanese.  I can get it to replace the first two characters but not the entire word. Based on what I read on here, here is what I came up with, but it's not working.  What am I doing wrong?

```
automobiles$cars <- gsub(ignore.case=TRUE, "\\<^ho\\>", paste("ho", "Japanese"), automobiles$cars)
```

Comment: Could you please use `dput(automobiles$cars)` to show us what the data looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you replace all strings starting with "Ho" with "Japanese:

```
> cars <- c("Honda", "Audi", "Ford")

> cars
[1] "Honda" "Audi"  "Ford" 

> cars <- gsub("^Ho(.*)", "Japanese", cars, ignore.case = TRUE)

> cars
[1] "Japanese" "Audi"     "Ford"
```

Your code contains some very strange stuff, so I suspect that your data/question might be more complex than that. Please explain further if that is the case.

The catch is `^Ho(.*)`, which selects the complete string (`(.*)` is for "everything that follows") if the string starts (`^`) with "`Ho`".

Comment: that works, thank you @Fr.!  Like I said, I'm new to regexs and was tyring to piece together a solution based on what I read on here and other online resources.  I presume the (.*) refers to replacing the entire word and not just the first two characters?  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, the `(*)` part of the pattern basically "eats" the entire string. From your code, I was unsure exactly you were wishing for. I believe that you might not b understanding `paste` correctly, for instance: it is meant for string concatenation, so your code will replace your strings with `"ho Japanese` (see `?paste`). Also, if you are new to regex in R, I recommend using the package `stringr`.